# C Thread bad access error when input string (link list)

Tags: c, linked-list

I have been getting Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to push a string element into the stack. I've changed the `char* name` to `char name[21]` but the assignment char[21] is not assignable to curr->name. Also I've tried fgets but the error still there. Anyone know where the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct parts
{
    char* name;
    char* type;
    int quantity;
    int price;
    int num;

    struct parts * next;

}*head,*tail,*curr,komponen;

void menu();
void show_Parts();
void push(char* nm, char* tip, int jml, int harga, int nom);
void del();

int main() {

    menu();


    del();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void push(char* nm, char* tip, int jml, int harga, int nom)
{
    // 1.
    curr = (struct parts *)malloc(sizeof(struct parts));
    // 2.
    if (curr == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }

    head = NULL;
    head = curr->next;

    curr->name = nm;
    curr->type = tip;
    curr->quantity = jml;
    curr->price = harga;
    curr->num = nom;

    curr = head;

    //

    printf("Input name of the new item [3..20]: ");
    scanf("%s",nm);
    if (strlen(nm) < 3 || strlen(nm) > 20) {
        printf("Length of name must between 3 and 20");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Input type of the new item [processor/graphic card/memory]: ");
    scanf("%s",tip);
    if (tip != "processor" || tip != "graphic card" || tip != "memory") {
        printf("Input type of existing item. Error");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Input quantity of the new item [1..20]: ");
    scanf("%d",&jml);
    if (jml < 1 || jml > 20) {
        printf("Quantity between 1 and 20\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Input price of new item [$1..$1000]: ");
    scanf("%d",&harga);
    if (harga < 1 || harga > 1000) {
        printf("Price between 1 and 1000\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    nom++;

    printf("--- Add New Item Success ---\n");

    tail->next = NULL;
}

void del()
{
    if (curr == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    }
    curr = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(curr);
}


void menu()
{
    int choic;
    do {
    printf("BLUE COMPUTER ADMINISTRATOR\n");
    printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    printf("1. Item list\n");
    printf("2. Add <PUSH> New item\n");
    printf("3. Exit\n");
    printf(">> Input your choice : ");

    switch (choic) {
        case 1:
            show_Parts();
            break;
        case 2:
            push(komponen.name,komponen.type,komponen.price,  komponen.quantity, komponen.num);
            break;
        case 3:
            del();
            exit(0);
            break;
    }
    scanf("%d",&choic);

    } while (choic != 3);
}


void show_Parts()
{
    if (curr == NULL) {
        printf("No item in list\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("            ---- ITEM LIST ----         \n\n");
    printf("-----+------------------+--------+-----------+--------\n");
    printf("|No. |    Name          |  Type  |  Quantity | Price|\n");
    do {
    printf("|%d  |%s                |%s      |%d         |%d      \n",curr->num, curr->name, curr->type, curr->quantity, curr->price);
        curr = curr->next;
    }while (curr != NULL);

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `head = curr->next;` : `curr->next` is uninitialezed. It should not be overwritten. maybe `curr->next = head;`...`head = curr;`

Comment: `push(komponen.name,...` : `komponen` is not input data at first time.

Comment: `curr->name = nm;` and `char* name to char name[21]` : `strcpy(curr->name, nm);`

Comment: What should I do with `komponen`?

Comment: E.g `case 2: /* input to komponen here then push*/
            push(komponen.name,komponen.type,komponen.price,  komponen.quantity, komponen.num);`

Comment: that fixed it. Thanks.